extracting a value from html string in bash
I am trying to write a script, which calls an API using curl:
#!/bin/bash
                                                                                                                                                                                    
cmd="curl ....."
result=`$cmd"`
echo $result

Result is as follows:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\"><html><head><title>201 Created</title></head><body><h1>Created</h1><form action=https://10.33.127.2/app/v1/tickets//2861-lrJzTzGkXDq7RHQoJKS6Z5j2NKZLqJTVtU7vJcrVHrjgtYW5xo-FA2PO64otnevmy method="POST">Service:<input type="text" name="service" value=""><br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form></body></html>

I need to extract value of  'action' and store it in a variable.
What is convenient way of doing it? I guess sed can help, but not sure how to use it for parsing.
PS: Its a protected env, and I cant install any utility.

Don't store the command in a variable. Don't forget to quote the argument to echo. Try https://shellcheck.net/ for basic diagnostics.

You can use grep https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-grep-command-to-search-files-in-linux/
#!/bin/bash

# Extract the action value
action=$(echo "$result" | grep -oP '(?<=action=)[^ ]*')
echo "$action"


Probably don't repeat all the errors in the OP's script. Try https://shellcheck.net/ for diagnostics.

i just added the last 3 strings i probably should have checked lol.
